# Populating the right-hand side of RichFaces picklist

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I'm on RichFaces 4.5.2.Final and JSF 2.1 and want to use picklist component. I currently write the following markup:

```
<rich:pickList id="lotoGames2" var="game"
    value="#{jackpot.selectedGameList}" 
    converter="gameConverter"
    listsHeight="100px" sourceListWidth="100px" targetListWidth="100px">

    <f:selectItems value="#{jackpotBean.availableLotoGames}"  var="game" itemValue="#{game}" itemLabel="#{game.name}" />
    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">
        <h:outputText value="#{msgs['drawForm.availableGames']}" />
    </f:facet>

    <f:facet name="targetCaption">
        <h:outputText value="#{msgs['drawForm.selectedGames']}" />
    </f:facet>

    <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{game.name}" />
    </rich:column>
</rich:pickList>
```

Left hand side is being populating fine, but right-hand side is not. I don't know what's a problem with it. I set a breakpoint to the setter of `jackpot.selectedGameList` and made sure that it returns actual value, but the `List` returned by it not rendered in the right-hand side. What the problem could it be with?

UPD: Accroding to BalusC's comment it seems important to mention that the `"#{jackpot.selectedGameList}"` is reffered to `List<GameDTO>` where `GameDTO` overrides `hashCode` and `equals` methods.

Here is how `GameDTO` looks like:

```
public class GameDTO {

    private int id;
    private String code;
    private String name;

    //Constructor, GET, SET

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {

        if (this == object) {
            return true;
        }

        if (object == null || getClass() != object.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        GameDTO other = (GameDTO) object;
        return id > 0 && other.id > 0 && id == other.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid the obvious: does the object representing the item value have `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) implemented, so JSF could compare it to available items? (this would however have caused another problem: being unable to submit selected items due to "Validation Error: Value is not valid").

Comment: @BalusC `#{jackpot.selectedGameList}` is reffered to `List<GameDTO>` and yes, `GameDTO` overrides both `hashCode` and `equals` methods. Should I remove that? Is the problem in it?

Comment: @BalusC Could you look at my updated quetion? I provided a little bit more information about the object.

Comment: OK, if that part is already implemented and works properly, then it's a RichFaces specific problem.

Comment: @BalusC Is it fixable within JSF context or should I dig into somewhere else?

Comment: If e.g. `<h:selectManyListbox>` works fine on that preselected value and available items, then it's a RichFaces specific problem.

Comment: Your `rich:pickList` can be simplified by removing `<rich:column>` part (you have already defined `itemLabel` with the same value) and moving `sourceCaption` and `targetCaption` (using attributes of `rich:pickList` with the same name). Check if getter for  `selectedGameList` return proper values (it can be called more that once).